# ASP.NET Application Life Cycle using Load Balancer

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, load-balancing

What are the events will get triggered when load balancer allot a different machine to server the request.

Say Client A request a page1 for the first time, load balancer allotted Server1 to serve the request. Entire application / page life cycle will get executed.

Now if Client A sends another request to get page2 but this time if load balancer allotted Server2 to serve the request, whether the entire application / page life cycle will get executed or not. If not, then which events will get triggered in this case.

Moving to more specific question : - Will it execute session_start again?

> Edited:  Well sorry forgot to mention that I am using Azure and don't
>   have control to set/change the configuration of balancer. Moreover,
>   our Adminstrators will not do so. We are at the application
>   development side.
>
> Also Note: we are ***NOT*** allowed to use out of proc sessions. so cannot
>   use sql azure to manage sessions.

Comment: this depends on the load balancer configuration.  I would not rely on sessions in a load balancer situation if possible to improve scalability

Comment: @Dreamwalker, we cannot change balancer's configuration. what is the alternative of sessions then? we cannot use cookies as it is not restful

Comment: You can use cookies in restful services if that's what you mean?  The only thing you can do if cookies are no go is send information in your requests so you can identify the user.  But essentially it's still a cookie you just moved it from the request header.

Comment: Should point out that on azure you don't need to use SQL Azure for session you can use table storage a lot cheaper but slower.  Also there is the cache worker role not looked at that one yet my self though.

Answer (score 1):

These words come from Microsoft themselves:

> Microsoft doesn’t publish load balancing algorithms on Azure and
>   **doesn’t make any guarantees that it will be round-robin**. Internally we
>   know that it is not as simple as round robin. There are multiple
>   factors taken into account when working out the best suitable
>   resources to direct your request to. For example, network proximity
>   make be taken into account providing that machine has capacity to
>   serve this request so you may see some sort of bias in the algorithm
>   depending on the location of services. There are some internal
>   optimizations included in algorithms to leverage knowledge of internal
>   structure, network performance and available capacity, type of load
>   balancer (software/hardware) etc... The goal of load balancing
>   algorithm is to route your request to the available resource in the
>   most efficient manner. Product team is calling it “roughly round
>   robin” algorithm.
>
> The only documented load balancing algorithms are on [Traffic Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/hh744833.aspx)
>   which can be used to control user traffic distribution.

Comment: +1, one important factor is "keep-alive" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12621531/57428

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure uses **Round Robin** load balancing scheme thus in-proc sessions are a "NO GO" in Windows Azure (especially cloud services). In the scenario you mentioned above, when the client requests "page2" which gets served from "server 2", then session_start event will get fired.

You may want to look into [Windows Azure Caching](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) functionality in Windows Azure and use that as an alternative to in-proc session management. In fact, there's a custom session state provider which makes use of this cache: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx.

Comment: there is also the cache role now http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11829.how-to-use-worker-cache-role-in-windows-azure.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As said, in order for the session to be shared in webfarms the the machine key must be shared across all servers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations
The default Asp.net session, being in proc doesn't allow much scalability (until you don't move to sql session), but this can be easily changed to be out of proc, resulting with the session being independant from your app and solving the issue of having multiple servers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx.

If you need to scale and have some cash to spend, consider to use StateServer session (out of process) or something like Memcached.

This said, the asp.net lifecycle get always fully executed per request, regardless of how many servers are in the farm. But the way the asp.net Session works remains the same (session_start will be always triggered once per session) what changes is it's configuration(sql, stateserver etc). [Have a look at this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416137/Understanding-Session-Management-Techniques-in-ASP) , there are some info you'll find useful.

Comment: "Session_start will be always triggered once per session" , here as server2 don't hold any session info of clientA so does it means it will trigger Session_start again?

Comment: do we need to install any external dlls for memchached?

Comment: @anilpurswani for memcache check their documentation. In short about Session_start: with In-proc you got multiple starts of the session. With sqlsession/stateserver you get 1 session and 1 Session_Start (session is stored outside on a different server and the servers in your farm will user it).